# Matlab Polynomial y=3*x.^2-12*x+20./x.^2-7*x+10

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I have the following assignment question:

[image: This is the question]

I have written the following code but can't seem to get the graph right.

```
x=[0:0.01:7];
p=[3 -12 20 ];
pb=[1 -7 10];
[h,r] = deconv(p,pb);
y=polyval([h,r],x);
plot(x,y);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `deconv` is appropriate here. Just evaluate _each_ polynomial with `polyval`,  then divide the results element-wise with `./`

Comment: thanks luis but im new to this can you help out maybe adjusting the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
x=0:0.01:7;

p=[3 -12 20 ];
pb=[1 -7 10];

num = polyval(p,x);
den = polyval(pb,x);
y = num ./ den;    % element-wise division of numerator and denominator
plot(x , y);
```